# How to sort Associative Arrays?

Tags: d

```
float[float] aa = [2.2:7.7, 3.3:6.6, 1.1:4.4];
std.sort(aa);
assert(aa == [1.1:4.4, 2.2:7.7, 3.3:6.6]);
```

The above doesn't work.  How does one sort `aa` in place ?

Comment: Do you need the rsults in a given order or do you just need to check that two distinct AA instances are equivalent?

Comment: @ I need the results in a given order, just like `std::map`.  I'll probably end up using `std.container`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

D's built-in associative arrays are [hash tables](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table). They're unsorted, and it makes no sense to sort them. The only time that sorting would make any sense would be when iterating over the AA, and to do that requires putting them in a new container. So, you could do something like

```
auto keys = aa.keys;
sort(keys);
```

but you can't sort the AA itself. If you want a sorted map, then you need to use something like [`std.container.RedBlackTree`](http://dlang.org/phobos/std_container.html#RedBlackTree) - though it does take a little bit of work to make it function as a map rather than a set (e.g. the sort function must sort on the key only, and when passing stuff to some functions, you need a tuple with a dummy value).

This is why Java has a `HashMap` and a `SortedMap` and why C++ has `unordered_map` (C++11) and `map`. They both are maps both they have very different characteristics - particularly with regards to sorting and lookup times.

Answer (score 6):

You can't -- it doesn't make sense.

Associative arrays are also known as "dictionaries" or "maps"; the particular variation in D is a hashtable. They are **not** arrays. Sorting them would *break* their ability to give you a fast lookup time.

If you need a fast lookup time, consider using [`RedBlackTree`](http://dlang.org/phobos/std_container.html#RedBlackTree) instead.

Comment: `std::map` is sorted, whereas `std::unordered_map` isn't.  Instead of associative array, perhaps they should call it `hash`.

Comment: @Arlen Associative array is a perfectly valid term. Personally, I would have called it a hash table, but calling it an associative array is perfectly accurate: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Associative_array

Comment: @Arlen: It also calls them associative arrays.